# jQuery Modal + .show() and .hide()

Tags: jquery, html, css

Please visit this [link](http://fakedc.com/sites/luilui/#!/colecao)
Click on first Image. Now is showing the Modal page (i used this jquery.nyroModal) to show this.

Ok, Now, click on "aqui" above the image.

On this action i simple do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){       

            $('#produtos').hide();
            $('#wrapper_detalhes').show();

            $('#exibe_detalhes').click(function(e) {
                $('#wrapper_detalhes').show();
                $('#produtos').hide();
                e.preventDefault;
                return false;
            });

            $('#exibe_produtos').click(function(e) {
                $('#wrapper_detalhes').hide();
                $('#produtos').show();
                e.preventDefault;
                return false;
            });         

            });
```

hide one div, and show another, but on the second div i was showing `id=produtos` when i click on "aqui" again, on my modal windo, appears scrollbars... but the `height` and `width` are the same as the first time i open the modal...

whats happening???

PS: The bars apears only on Chrome. On IE its showing very nice! I dont tested on Firefox

Comment: Can't reproduce in Safari. No scroll bar appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply a css overflow:hidden rule to the modal. It should force any scroll bars to go away.

```
#modal { overflow: hidden; }
```